# OCaml: Permutation of every value in two sets? (how to translate this from Java)

Tags: java, ocaml, permutation

I have two sets, returned by Set.Make(t). I would like to generate every possible combination of the values in the two. How can I do this?

This works to generate some pairs, but not all:

```
List.combine (IntSet.elements odp) (IntSet.elements ftw)
```

This would do it in Java:

```
for (int i : ktr) {
     for (int m : mnx) {
       System.out.println(i + ", " + m);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `xs` and `ys` are two lists, then their cartesian product (returning a list of pairs) can be computed as follows:

```
List.concat (List.map (fun x -> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))
                                         ys)
                      xs)
```

In this case your `xs` and `ys` are `IntSet.elements odp` and `IntSet.elements ftw`

Answer (score 6):

Combining @David Crawshaw's solution (which is tail-recursive) with @newacct's (which is fully generic):

```
let cartesian_product xs ys =
  List.fold_left (fun acc x -> 
    List.fold_left (fun acc y -> 
      (x,y) :: acc) 
      acc ys) 
    [] xs

let product = 
  cartesian_product (IntSet.elements odb) (IntSet.elements ftw)
```

This will reverse the natural ordering. It can be regained by applying `List.rev` to the result (`List.rev` is also tail-recursive).

Comment: this doesn't type check:

Error: This expression has type 'a -> ('b * 'a) list -> ('b * 'a) list
       but is here used with type 'a -> ('b * 'a) list -> 'a

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the Cartesian product of two sets.

This question has been asked [in a thread](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2009/07/a506d37925c45ca4bb94ea22f66d308f.en.html) on the OCaml mailing list. This answer is offered by [Brian Hurt](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2009/07/002e5bd3f4f6b73a4f7829afbd339913.en.html): For

```
module TypeSet = Set.Make(Type);;
```

Create, to represent the product:

```
module TypeType = struct
    type t = Type.t * Type.t;;
    let compare (x1, x2) (y1, y2) =
        let r = Type.compare x1 y1 in
        if r == 0 then
            Type.compare x2 y2
        else
            r
    ;;
end;;

module TypeTypeSet = Set.Make(TypeType);;
```

Then generate the product with:

```
let cartesian_product s1 s2 =
    let f x y t = TypeTypeSet.add (x, y) t in
    let g x t = TypeSet.fold (f x) s2 t in
    TypeSet.fold g s1 TypeTypeSet.empty
;;
```